# Index out of bounds (CSES permutations problem) java

Tags: java, permutation

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class cses6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        String m = "";

        ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> stringjoin = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        if (1 < n && n< 4) {
            System.out.println("NO SOLUTION");
        }

        even.set(0, 4);
        even.set(1, 2);
        odd.add(0, 1);
        
        for (int i = 1; i < n+1 && i > 4; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                even.add(i);
            } else {
                odd.add(i);
            }


        }
        odd.addAll(even);

        for (int i = 1; i < odd.size(); i++) {
            m = Integer.toString(odd.get(i));
            stringjoin.set(i,m);
        }

        System.out.println(stringjoin.toString().replace(", ", " ").replace("[", "").replace("]",""));

        
    }
}
```

My problem is:
Input

The only input line contains an integer n.

Output

Print a beautiful permutation of integers 1,2,…,n. If there are several solutions, you may print any of them. If there are no solutions, print "NO SOLUTION".

However, i get the index out of bounds error. Which part of my code is wrong and how can i resolve the error?
Error takes place at line 19

Comment: Which line is line 19? Please add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: `even.set(0, 4);` when you are doing this the `even` list is still empty

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < n+1 && i > 4; i++)` - how does this even work?

Answer (score -1):

The wrong code is here

```java
even.set(0, 4);
```

and the reason is here

```java
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        rangeCheck(index);

        E oldValue = elementData(index);
        elementData[index] = element;
        return oldValue;
    }

    private void rangeCheck(int index) {
        if (index >= size)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
    }
```

You cannot use the `set(int index, E element)` method to an empty ArrayList